# Selecting all the checkboxes inside divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to select all the checkboxes once the "select all" checkbox is clicked. Here`s is the code

```
<div class="fp">
  <div class="fpanel">
    <div class="fpblockscontainer"> 
      <span class="fpblockslabel">Merchants</span>    
      <div class="fpblocks">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input class=".select-all2" type="checkbox">Select All</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox">Apple</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox">orange</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox">potato</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox">Williams-Sonoma</label>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Here I need to select all the checkbox once the "select.all2" checkbox is selected. The below jquery code is not working. Where am I wrong?

```
$(".select-all2").on("click", function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("div.fp").find(':checkbox').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
  } else {
    $(this).closest("div.fp").find(':checkbox').each(function () {
      $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just remove dot from your input, and it should work fine

```
<input class=".select-all2" type="checkbox" >
```

to

```
<input class="select-all2" type="checkbox" >
```

See here: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4rxz/)

Answer (score 4):

remove `.` from class

```
 <input class="select-all2" type="checkbox" >
       //------^----here
```

use prop() instead of attr()

```
 $(this).prop('checked', true); //to check the checkbox

 $(this).prop('checked', false); //to uncheck the checkbox
```

and you don't need each() loop

try this

```
 $(".select-all2").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest("div.fpblocks").find(":checkbox").prop('checked',true);

    } else {
       $(this).closest("div.fpblocks").find(":checkbox").prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sVyb9/)

Answer (score 4):

The click isn't fired because the markup includes the `.` in the classname.

```
<input class=".select-all2" type="checkbox" >
```

should be:

```
<input class="select-all2" type="checkbox" >
```

The script can also be made more concise:

```
$(".select-all2").click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/uY8yu/

Answer (score 0):

try this for select/deselect. This will change state of `select-all2` when individual checkboxes are checked/unchecked also.

```
var $ch = $(".select-all2").change(function() {
    $all.prop('checked', $ch.filter(':checked').length == $ch.length);
}),
$all = $('.checkbox input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
  $ch.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pQxBC/)